# How to force the loading of the group file

Tags: linux, groups

This is on a CentOS 5.3 server

I am logged in as myUser.
myUser is added to a new group while logged in. (root edits the /etc/group file in another session)
How can I get the change to take effect without logging out and logging back in?

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the user run:

```
exec su $USER
```

Or:

```
exec sudo -u $USER -s
```

That will replace their login shell with a new login shell that's been freshly logged in as them.  su will definitely prompt them for their password.  sudo might not, but I believe will require configuring /etc/sudoers so the user has permission to run a shell as themselves. If you leave out the "exec", the user will have to "exit" twice.

On Unix, when you login there's a period where there's software running as root that's authenticated the user, which then sets up the groups before switching to running a shell as that user.  After that, there's no way to change the permissions without involving software run as root again.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much impossible because the login session reads at the beginning the group file. If you initiate a new login session you might be able to do it but i think it is not possible.